# facing error everytime in uploading a file in github

Tags: git, github, ssl, windows-7

i tried 4.5 .net framework installed,access token,username password access everything as they asked for.but didn't succeeded.this is all problem  i face from yesterday. i use windows 7 ultimate service pack 1.

git error like this

```
Home_System@Home_System-PC MINGW64 ~/Desktop/myproj (master)
$ git commit -m "first commit"
[master (root-commit) ef8fd3c] first commit
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 hello.py
 create mode 100644 my.py

Home_System@Home_System-PC MINGW64 ~/Desktop/myproj (master)
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean

Home_System@Home_System-PC MINGW64 ~/Desktop/myproj (master)
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/arshad007hossain/myproj.git

Home_System@Home_System-PC MINGW64 ~/Desktop/myproj (master)
$ git pull origin master
fatal: couldn't find remote ref master

Home_System@Home_System-PC MINGW64 ~/Desktop/myproj (master)
$ git pull origin master
fatal: couldn't find remote ref master

Home_System@Home_System-PC MINGW64 ~/Desktop/myproj (master)
$ git push --force origin master
fatal: An error occurred while sending the request.
fatal: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
Logon failed, use ctrl+c to cancel basic credential prompt.
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.
remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/arshad007hossain/myproj.git/'
```

Comment: This is almost certainly related to the fact that you're using an obsolete operating system with no updates or security support.  At least the "Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel" part.

Comment: do i have to use higher operating system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, the credentials that are being sent to GitHub contain something that is not a personal access token or OAuth token.  That is not helped by your credential manager likely being Git Credential Manager Core, which uses .NET.  Since you're using an operating system (Windows 7) with no security updates or other fixes, this is probably not helping GCM Core to work properly.

Windows 7 doesn't necessarily support TLS 1.2 properly, and as a result, when GCM Core won't work properly.  TLS 1.2 is considered the minimum secure version of TLS on the Internet these days, and most websites, including GitHub, don't support anything less.

It's also generally responsible to make sure you're running a system receiving regular security updates, because it prevents your computer from being compromised and used to launch attacks on other systems.  Even if you don't care about the security and integrity of your data, other folks will appreciate your system not being a bot in a DDoS network.

If you really need to push in the meantime, you can try to switch to the `wincred` credential helper, which might not have this problem, and then remove all of the existing credentials using the following commands:

```
$ git config --unset-all credential.helper
$ git config --global credential.helper wincred
$ echo url=https://github.com | git credential reject
```

Once you've done that, you should then be prompted tor a username and password when you push.  Enter your username when prompted, and when prompted for a password, go to [GitHub's Personal Access Token page](https://github.com/settings/tokens), generate a token with the `repo` and `gist` scopes, and then paste that token in *instead* of entering your password.  That should make things work for the moment.

Comment: How did you learn so much?